# Plutus: multiple-utxo withdraw fails, single-utxo withdraw succeeds

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, transaction

A beneficiary tries to withdraw the maximum amount from 2 utxo's of a smart contract in one transaction but that fails. If the beneficiary does it in two steps it succeeds.
**Why does the first one fail?**

**Detail** :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ben         | addr_test1v⋯qarpt4  | = 1101556208 |
            | - 714d2e⋯dea7cb#0   | +    1021470 | [ "ben"×1 ] Token
            | - 714d2e⋯dea7cb#1   | + 1100534738 | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
tokencheck  | addr_test1w⋯hyha8n  | =   34000000 |
            | - 347def⋯58e2c7#0   | +   21000000 | {14e594⋯4816fa} Datum
            | - dca3bc⋯b80ae8#0   | +   13000000 | {14e594⋯4816fa} Datum
```

The beneficiary 'ben' tries to withdraw the maximum amount from smart contract 'tokencheck',
and in that transaction also includes his token 'ben' (62656e),  to fulfill a condition in the contract.

Ben tries to withdraw from both the utxo's of the contract (both have the same, correct datum) :

```
# total amount = 21000000 (contract) + 13000000 (contract) + 1021470 (ben token) - 966660 (fee) = 34054810

cardano-cli transaction build-raw
  --babbage-era
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --tx-in "714d2e⋯dea7cb#0"                    # utxo with ben's token
  --tx-in "347def⋯58e2c7#0"                    # first utxo of contract
  --tx-in "dca3bc⋯b80ae8#0"                    # second utxo of contract
  --tx-in-datum-file datum.json
  --tx-in-redeemer-file redeemer.json
  --tx-in-script-file tokencheck.json
  --tx-in-collateral "714d2e⋯dea7cb#1"
  --required-signer ben.skey
  --tx-out "addr_test1v⋯qarpt4 + 34054810 + 1 2d99fb⋯63d3a1.62656e"
  --fee 966660
  --tx-in-execution-units '(3000000000,7000000)'
  --out-file tx_raw.json
```

This fails when submitting, with error message:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError 
ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError 
[UtxowFailure( 
  FromAlonzoUtxowFail 
    (MissingRedeemers [(Spending (TxIn (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "347def⋯58e2c7"}) (
        TxIx 0)),ScriptHash "5c2d3c⋯7d947b")])),
UtxowFailure (
  UtxoFailure (FromAlonzoUtxoFail (UtxosFailure (CollectErrors
    [NoRedeemer (Spending (TxIn (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "347def⋯58e2c7"}) (TxIx 0)))])))
    )
])
```

If Ben just withdraws using only ONE of the contract's utxo's, the transaction succeeds:

```
# total amount = 21000000 + 1021470 - 953284 = 21068186

cardano-cli transaction build-raw
  --babbage-era
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --tx-in "714d2e⋯dea7cb#0"                    # utxo with ben's token
  --tx-in "347def⋯58e2c7#0"                    # one utxo of contract
  --tx-in-datum-file datum.json
  --tx-in-redeemer-file redeemer.json
  --tx-in-script-file tokencheck.json
  --tx-in-collateral "714d2e⋯dea7cb#1"
  --required-signer ben.skey
  --tx-out "addr_test1v⋯qarpt4 + 21068186 + 1 2d99fb⋯63d3a1.62656e"
  --fee 953284
  --tx-in-execution-units '(3000000000,7000000)'
  --out-file tx_raw.json

Transaction successfully submitted.
```

**Question**: why does the first transaction fail while the second succeeds?

**Update**

Here's the contract, it's written in Helios:

```
struct Datum {
    donor:        PubKeyHash
    beneficiary:  PubKeyHash
    policy:       MintingPolicyHash
}

func main(datum: Datum, ctx: ScriptContext) -> Bool {
    tx: Tx = ctx.tx;
    if (tx.is_signed_by(datum.donor)) {
        true
    } else { 
        if ( tx.value_sent_to(datum.beneficiary).get(AssetClass::new(datum.policy, #62656e)) == 1) { 
            true
        } else {
            print("computer says no"); false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does contract only allows one input utxo that requires script to be consumed per transaction? Can you check or share the contract code too.

Comment: Contract added to the text above. 
I don't think the problem is with the contract's code, because it would give a different error.

Comment: Yeah i see. Could it be due to build-raw requiring tx-in-script-file, datum redeemer for each input. I think it can be repeated and order matters. You can try that but not sure if it automatically uses same script, datum, redeemer for two inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is, as Nabin suggested, to repeat after each contract-utxo the datum/redeemer/script and execution units arguments as shown here:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw
  --babbage-era      
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --tx-in "344b8c⋯a3325e#0"                     # utxo with ben's token
  --tx-in "9b7697⋯dbb2e4#0"                     # contract utxo #1
  --tx-in-datum-file datum.json
  --tx-in-redeemer-file redeemer.json  
  --tx-in-script-file tokencheck.json
  --tx-in-execution-units '(3000000000,7000000)'
  --tx-in "f44eee⋯db6906#0"                     # contract utxo #2
  --tx-in-datum-file datum.json
  --tx-in-redeemer-file redeemer.json  
  --tx-in-script-file tokencheck.json
  --tx-in-execution-units '(3000000000,7000000)'
  --tx-in-collateral "344b8c⋯a3325e#1"
  --required-signer ben.skey
  --tx-out "addr_test1v⋯qarpt4 + 33323655 + 1 2d99fb⋯63d3a1.62656e"  
  --fee 1697815
  --out-file tx_raw.json
```

Transaction successfully submitted.

Comment: Indeed: datum/redeemer and script need to be specified for each utxo separately